# Maximizing area of rectangle inscribed in circle sector of radius 2

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

A rectangle is inscribed in a circle sector. The top two corners of the rectangle lies on the radius of the circle sector and the bottom two corners lie on the arc of the circle sector.

[image]
The radius is 2 and angle is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Find the maximum area of the rectangle that has these properties and are located exactly like this using calculus-based optimization.

**Attempted solution:**

Let the shorter side of the rectangle be labelled x and the longer be labelled y. The distance from the center of the circle to the top of the rectangle is b.

Now, create a dashed-line triangle from the center of the circle to the bottom right of the rectangle. Call the top angle $\alpha$.

From this, we can get a value for $\frac{y}{2}$, since this is the side opposite the angle:

$$\sin \alpha = \frac{\frac{y}{2}}{2} \Rightarrow y = 4 \sin \alpha$$

Using the same triangle but with the adjacent side x + b:

$$\cos \alpha = \frac{x+b}{2} \Rightarrow x = 2 \cos \alpha - b$$

Then we use half of the top triangle above the rectangle to get a value for b in terms of y:

$$\tan \frac{2\pi}{6} = \frac{\frac{y}{2}}{b} \Rightarrow b = \frac{\frac{1}{2}y}{\tan \frac{\pi}{3}}$$

Combining these to get a value for x:

$$x = 2 \cos \alpha - b = 2 \cos \alpha - \frac{\frac{1}{2}y}{\tan \frac{\pi}{3}} = 2 \cos \alpha - \frac{2 \sin \alpha}{\tan \frac{\pi}{3}}$$

The area becomes:

$$A(\alpha) = yx = 4 \sin \alpha (2 \cos \alpha - \frac{2 \sin \alpha}{\tan \frac{\pi}{3}})$$

Taking the derivative:

$$A'(\alpha) = 8(-sin^2 \alpha + cos^2 \alpha - 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha)$$

Setting to zero:

$$A'(\alpha) = 0 \Rightarrow a = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8}$$

Putting this into the formula for A:

$$A( \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8}) = 4(\sqrt{2} -1)$$

However, this does not match the expected answer of $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$.

What went wrong? What are some productive ways to finish this off?

Comment: When you differentiated $A(\alpha)$, you dropped the $\tan \frac{\pi}{3} = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: There is a nice solution without analysis.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Would you be willing to give a hint for the nice solution without analysis? Thanks!

Comment: @andy87 If $CD$ is an altitude of $\Delta ABC$ with $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}$, so $CD^2=AD\cdot DB.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A'(\alpha) = 8(-\sin^{2}{\alpha} + \cos^{2}{\alpha} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha})$. Setting this to zero gives the family of solutions $\alpha = \frac{1}{6}(3 \pi n + \pi)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Taking $n = 0$ gives $A(\pi/6) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

I got $$A(\alpha)=\frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{2}-\frac{\sin^2(\alpha)}{\tan(60^{\circ})}$$ so $$A'(\alpha)=8\left(\cos(2\alpha)-\frac{\sin(2\alpha)}{\tan(60^{\circ})}\right)$$
and
$$A'(\alpha)=0$$ if $$\tan(2\alpha)=\tan(60^{\circ})$$